# Making a class with empty name using type

Tags: python

According to Python's documentation for the built-in function [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

> `class type(name, bases, dict, **kwds)`
>
> [...]
>
> With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the [`class`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class) statement. The *name* string is the class name and becomes the [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__) attribute.

I have realized that the *name* string might as well be empty, and the function invocation would still work:

```py
>>> type('', (), {})
<class '__main__.'>
```

Is there any issue that might arise from doing it?

Comment: I get an error with `None` by the way

Comment: I'm going to say "yes", but obviously if I could tell you exactly what issue to expect, it wouldn't be expected.

Comment: "So I am wondering, is there any unexpected issue that might arise from doing it?" It's kind of hard to know what you might expect. Perhaps code might expect `C.__name__` to not be falsey, but that seems contrived (why would someone do `if C.__name__: ....`?)

Comment: From another perspective, one might consider any string that is not a valid Python identifier as a problematic argument, since identifiers are the only thing that a `class` statement can provide to the metaclass.

Comment: @chepner not sure why that should matter, unless you write code that makes that assumption, but I'm having a hard time seeing that as anything other than a problem with the code making that assumption

Comment: My assumption is more that failing to know what might use the `__name__` attribute, it's almost inconceivable that a valid `class` statement could produce a value that would cause problems.

Comment: Since some of you correctly took issues with the imprecise word "unexpected", I decided to remove it. But yes, broadly I don't see why this practice would be a problem other than with very contrived and problematic code...

Comment: @chepner you are right, I realized that _any_ name string is accepted by `type`, even though it's not a valid identifier. The above codes is still working with `' '`, `'\n'` or `'*+#^'`

Comment: I will add that I verified in a longer example that the class and its inheritance mechanisms work as expected

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is a matter of opinion, and I could say that in my opinion, it is correct to assume valid identifiers as class names, but more importantly than the opinion, Python itself makes that assumption e.g. in the `pickle` library. There are probably also other places where e.g. an identifier containing dots would fail. Only explicitly allowing such things in the official docs and correcting all libraries would make arbitrary names truly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one thing which won't work correctly: `pickle`.

This works, because it has a valid identifier for class name:

```
>>> Good = type('Good', (), {})
>>> setattr(__main__, 'Good', Good)
>>> good = Good()
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(good))
<__main__.Good object at 0x7ff0d8173160>
```

This does not work, because the class name is empty:

```
>>> Bad = type('', (), {})
>>> setattr(__main__, '', Bad)
>>> bad = Bad()
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(bad))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

I am sure there are other places where one could encounter problems. Using the "normal" way to define types does not allow class names like `''` or `'77'`. It is correct for any function to assume that.

When using `type` to create a new type, one should make sure that the same restrictions are followed, instead of assuming that libraries are going to handle invalid identifiers as if they were valid.